# Word VBA Concatenated strings and combo box tags

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write a script that will takes in the chapter heading, saves it as a string and creates a combo box with the chapter heading plus some additional text as the tag.

```vb
   Dim Combo_Box As ContentControl
    Dim Combo_Heading_1 As String
    Dim Combo_Heading_2 As String
    Dim Combo_Tag As String
    Dim Initial_Position As Range
    Dim Heading_Selection As Range
    Combo_Heading_2 = "aaa"

    Set Initial_Position = Selection.Range
    Initial_Position.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart

    With Initial_Position.Find
        .Forward = False
        .Style = "Heading 1"

        If .Execute Then
            Set Heading_Selection = Initial_Position
            Combo_Heading_1 = Heading_Selection.Text
        End If
    End With 

    Combo_Tag = Combo_Heading_1 & Combo_Heading_2

    MsgBox Combo_Tag

    Set Combo_Box = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList, Selection.Range)

    With Combo_Box.DropdownListEntries
        .Add "[PASS]"
        .Add "[FAIL ]"
        Combo_Box.Tag = Combo_Tag
        Combo_Box.SetPlaceholderText , , "[         ]"
    End With

    For Each Combo_Box In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        With Combo_Box.Range.Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .Size = 11
            .ColorIndex = wdBlack
        End With
    Next Combo_Box
   
    Set Combo_Box = Nothing     

End Sub
```

That's what I've got so far. The tag needs to be made from two  concatenated strings. I've added a line to create a message box that shows what stored in "Combo_Tag" which seems to show both strings concatenated correctly but the combo box tag only shows the first string. I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Comment: `the combo box tag only shows the first string.` - note that the combo box tag is never displayed at all, it is only used to identify the control from within your program. Perhaps you wanted to change the Title?

Comment: I am checking the tag using the properties button on the controls section of the developer tab. My eventual intention is to set one combo box as the "parent" of all the combo boxes under that particular heading so that when I change the value of the "parent" all the other combo boxes in that heading section change to match. This script is just to create the boxes.

Comment: That would probably explain your problem: your combo_tag has multiple lines (paragraphs), which works fine, but the properties button will only show the first line. Check the actual tag through the immediate window (`?ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).Tag`)

Comment: That's it. The code to save the heading in Combo_Heading_1 is saving the entire thing including the "carriage return" or whatever it is called rather than just the text. I've added this line: Combo_Heading_1 = Left(Combo_Heading_1, Len(Combo_Heading_1) - 2)

Comment: Good! I'll make my comment into an answer for posteriority.

Answer (score 0):

Your combo_tag has multiple lines (paragraphs), because your search will find an entire paragraph including the end marker.

Putting multiple lines into the tag works fine, but the properties button will only show the first line. You can see the actual tag through the immediate window with: `?ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).Tag`

If you want the tag to contain a single line, remove the paragraph marker from Combo_Heading_1 first.